# EEA spouse residence card refused. What can I do?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens

My wife is British and also an EEA national exercising her treaty right. We came back to UK and I  applied for a residence card but has been refused on the grounds that I did not prove my wife's marital status. UK border alerted me that my wife was married before but what UKBA didn't know was she was divorced before we got married. UK border also said I have no right of appeal. What can I do now?

Comment: Did she include the prior marriage and divorce in the application?

Comment: You apparently have no right of appeal, but you are allowed to submit a new application. Your new application should remedy the deficiencies in your present application, of course. In particular you'll need to provide documentation of your wife's previous marriage and its dissolution.

Comment: In addition to @phoog's comment, if the prior marriage and dissolution were omitted, rather than just under-documented, check the rest of the application **very** carefully. If you made one mistake in completing the form, you may have made others.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply again submitting the proper documentary evidence to support the fact that she was previously married and divorced. You can do this at any time.