# EEA application for British Spouse - Second time with divorce papers included

Tags: united-kingdom, residence-cards

Thanks to everyone who responded to [the question about my EEA application in the UK](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8425/eea-spouse-residence-card-refused-what-can-i-do). That first application was refused on the grounds that my wife was on the Home Office records as still married to her previous husband. The home office didn't know that they had divorced a long time ago.

I have sent a fresh EEA spouse family residence application to the Home Office about a month ago. This new application included my wife's divorce papers and all the other supporting documents. The Home Office has not even acknowledged this new application. I think they are intentionally refusing to accept it. This application's postage is tracked and Royal Mail confirmed that they have delivered it to the Home Office.  Should I take any action against the Home Office because they are refusing to accept my new application. What can I do now?

Comment: How long ago did they receive it?

Comment: Did they acknowledge the original application before making their decision about it?

Comment: Yes,they acknowledged and kept it for six months before .it was a divorce certificate which was missing but instead for them to write me and ask for it ,they didn't

Comment: i have sent a new application with the missing divorce certificate which was missing in my application about a month and some weeks now but no reply at all from them

Comment: You should just ask the Home Office whether they received the application or not.